# How do I find the locations of automatic page breaks using Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a worksheet that spans multiple pages, both vertically and horizontally.  It has certain rows and columns that are set to repeat on each page.  I would like to know where these page breaks are going to be; I essentially want to get the information from Page Break Preview into my C# code so that I can fix things like cells that are merged across pages, and adding a signature box that is one page wide.

I tried using the Worksheet.HPageBreaks property, but the HPageBreaks.Count property is always null, even when I know that the worksheet has multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my own knowledge, Excel does not store that data internally, but rather calculates it closer to real time based on PageSettings, PrinterSettings, manually stored "PageBreak" markers, and cell sizes and content.

The best solution I could suggest would be attempting to calculate these things yourself.

I also freely admit that I could be completely wrong about this, but from my own experiences, this is likely the case.  I will update as//if//when my own research finds something new.

**Update: Link**

This is barely relevant, but on the same topic.  Perhaps it contains some examples or data that you can manipulate for your own ends.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/exceldev/thread/0d1fd9f2-9111-42c4-ad36-3082f4311202

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to place a custom footer on the last row of a page break.

On a new blank worksheet in landscape, the last row of the page is row 34.

Try it!

1. Open Excel
2. New Worksheet
3. Type "hi" in cell A1

You'll see the automatic page breaks (dotted lines) appear.

If the row heights don't change, each page has 34 rows.

**So place the footer every 34th row.**  Simple!

But get's hairier if there are rows with varying heights. Now you must roll up your sleeves and cook your own algorithm! The goal is to **find an offset that will always land you where you intent to**.

We know 1 row = 15 RowHeight points (on 100% dpi).  The approach is to find the **line break count** inside a given cell to determine how many rows to offset.

```
// cell w/ multiple lines of text 
Excel.Range rng = ws.get_Range("A3"); 

int lineBreakCnt = rng.Text.Count(x => x == '\n'); 

// if range is merged, it will not auto-adjust RowHeight. So:
int rowHeight = 15; // 15 points = 1 
int rowHeight = lineBreakCnt > 1 ? rowHeight * lineBreakCnt + (rowHeight / 2) : rowHeight * lineBreakCnt + rowHeight;

rng.RowHeight = rowHeight;

//Calc footer row
int footerRow = 34;

//depending how much cell contents push down, adjust footer row
if (lineBreakCnt == 1)
{
   footerRow -= (lineBreakCnt - 2) + 2;
}
else
if (lineBreakCnt > 1)
{
   footerRow -= (lineBreakCnt -2) + 1;
}

ws.get_Range("A" + footerRow).Formula = "Cool footer w/ formatted text here";
```

Test it out by plugging in multiple lines of text in A3.

If this helps you, please give it a like for support.